Power BI visualizations embed in Google Sheet
I am currently facing an issue. I have created a Sankey Diagram visualization in Microsoft Power BI using VisioChart. Now, I want to embed that visualization in Google Sheets, but I cannot find a way to do so. Can I get any solution for this? I am a beginner in Power BI and need assistance with this.
I have talked with Microsoft Power BI support but received no reply.

You'll not be able to embed a visual in google sheets, you have to take a screen grab and paste the image there
